# How to optimize Querybuilder query

Tags: aem, aem-6

I have this query -

```
group.p.or=true
type=cq:Page
p.limit=10
group.1_group.path=/content/path/path1
group.1_group.1_group.p.or=true
group.1_group.1_group.1_property.value=false
group.1_group.1_group.2_property=jcr:content/pageTemplateType
group.1_group.1_group.1_property=jcr:content/pageTemplateType
group.1_group.1_group.2_property.operation=unequals
group.1_group.1_group.1_property.operation=exists
group.1_group.1_group.2_property.value=template
group.1_group.path.self=true

group.2_group.path=/content/path/path-2
group.2_group.1_group.p.or=true
group.2_group.1_group.1_property.value=false
group.2_group.1_group.2_property=jcr:content/pageTemplateType
group.2_group.1_group.1_property=jcr:content/pageTemplateType
group.2_group.1_group.2_property.operation=unequals
group.2_group.1_group.1_property.operation=exists
group.2_group.1_group.2_property.value=template
group.2_group.path.self=true
```

What I am trying to do is that, query multiple paths and return the paths which has the property `pageTemplateType` value not equal to 'template' or the property `pageTemplateType` does not exists.

This query works fine but it takes long time more than 1 second. But if I just remove the `self` i.e `group.2_group.path.self=true` or `group.1_group.path.self=true` then it takes around only 0.02 second.
So I do not understand how to optimize it, how to use `self` efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a query with `path.self=true` will **NEVER** be fast in AEM. Better try to use another query, without the path.self=true.

Internally the QueryBuilder uses the `PredicateEvaluator's` to construct an XPath query `PredicateEvaluator.getXPathExpression(...)`. This translation is done with "best effort". Then the results of the XPath-query is filtered by all remaining predicates (which couldn't be fully converted to Xpath) `PredicateEvaluator.includes(...)`. See [Predicate API](https://developer.adobe.com/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/eval/PredicateEvaluator.html)

Now the PathPredicateEvaluator has a problem. The JCR-Path (at least in JackRabbit) does not support the descendant-or-self axis. So the XPath query `/content/path/path1/descendant-or-self::node()` is not supported. As result the XPath Query will search the entire repository, and the Path-Predicate uses the afterwards filtering. Probably it had been better, to search from the parent-node, instead from the repository-root. But thats the way it is implemented.

You can check that in the query debugger. http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html

---

You can test this behaviour with 2 simplified queries (in the query-debugger)

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/path/path1
```

The above query is straight translated into the following XPath:

```
/jcr:root/content/path/path1//element(*, cq:Page)
```

Now with self=true:

```
type=cq:Page
path=/content/path/path1
path.self=true
```

The above query is translated in the following XPath

```
//element(*, cq:Page)
```

And after iterating over all pages, the XPath-result-set is filtered with the following Java-Predicate:

```
{path=path: path=/content/path/path1, self=true}
```

---

Proposal to your issue:

1. Maybe you can use JCR-SQL2 queries, or a custom XPath-Query. For so complicated queries the QueryBuilder is not the best-choice anyway. But maybe you need to use it from the front-end. Then better stick with QueryBuilder, as only the QueryBuilder has a REST-API. The other options require Java-Code.
2. You searching for Page-Attributes. Instead of searching for a cq:Page, you can search for cq:PageContent. cq:PageContent-nodes will always be child-nodes (even for the root node). Then you don't need to include self. You only need to remove /jcr:content from the result-path (the page will be the parent of the result-node)

Here is the query for approach 2)

```
group.p.or=true
type=cq:PageContent
p.limit=10
group.1_group.path=/content/path/path1
group.1_group.1_group.p.or=true
  group.1_group.1_group.1_property=pageTemplateType
  group.1_group.1_group.1_property.operation=exists
  group.1_group.1_group.1_property.value=false

  group.1_group.1_group.2_property=pageTemplateType
  group.1_group.1_group.2_property.operation=unequals
  group.1_group.1_group.2_property.value=template


group.2_group.path=/content/path/path-2
group.2_group.1_group.p.or=true
  group.2_group.1_group.1_property=pageTemplateType
  group.2_group.1_group.1_property.operation=exists
  group.2_group.1_group.1_property.value=false

  group.2_group.1_group.2_property=pageTemplateType
  group.2_group.1_group.2_property.operation=unequals
  group.2_group.1_group.2_property.value=template
```

---

A starter XPath for approach 1) which searches `/content/path/path1` and `/content/path/path-2` would be the following (first use a XPath Union, and then the property condition):

```
(
    /jcr:root/content/path/element(path1, cq:Page)
  | /jcr:root/content/path/path1//element(*, cq:Page)
  | /jcr:root/content/path/element(path-2, cq:Page)
  | /jcr:root/content/path/path-2//element(*, cq:Page)
)
[
  jcr:content/@pageTemplateType != 'template'
  or not(jcr:content/@pageTemplateType)
]
```

PS: If the above XPath works depends on you indexes and the content. Probably it needs some improvement.